# Guardar variables de una función

Tags: r, rstudio

Si en RStudio hago

```
suma=4+5
```

Se guarda la variable suma, normalmente en una ventanita a la derecha, en una categoría llamada Values.

Si hago por ejemplo:

```
sum<- function(d1,d2) {
      suma=d1+d2
      mul=suma*9
      cat(paste0("El resultado es:", mul))
     
}

sum(4,5)
```

Obtengo el resultado, y se guarda la función, pero no se guarda de forma visual `suma` ni `mul` en la ventanita.

¿cómo puedo modificar la función para que sum se guarde de forma que pueda acceder a su resultado desde la ventanita de values?

Comment: El tema es de ámbito de vida de las variables. Cuando se declaran dentro de un método (función) sólo existen mientras el método está en ejecución. Una vez termina de ejecutarse dejan de existir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifica la función para que al finalizar te retorne el valor añadiendo return(mul) o simplemente mul.

```
sum <- function(d1, d2) {
       suma = d1 + d2
       mul = suma * 9
       print(paste0("El resultado es: ", mul))
       return(mul)     
}
```

Guarda el valor de la función sum() en una variable:

```
suma <- sum(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Las variables en R siempre están asociadas a un "entorno", que son como "cajas" dónde uno guarda cosas, normalmente símbolos que representan nombres de variables o funciones, importante: no guardan el dato sino el nombre o referencia al dato. Otro cosa importante, es que cada entorno guarda la referencia a su entorno "padre".

El panel que mencionas, es justamente el panel de inspección de entornos, de hecho la solapa se llama "Environment", y por defecto se muestra el "Global Environment", que vendría ser el entorno inicial del Script que tienes abierto. Ahora bien, cada función instancia su propio entorno privado y temporal, todas las variables locales se crean en este entorno y éste se destruye cuando finaliza la función y por consiguiente, nunca llegarás a ver los valores de estas variables una vez finalizada la función, eventualmente sí, peo en el caso que estuvieras haciendo un "debug" interactivo, cuando vayas paso a paso por el código de la función podrás ver el "entorno local" y ver estás variables.

Tiene poco sentido, pero si quisieras ver los valores de estás variables "locales", lo que se puede hacer es transformarlas en variables del entorno "padre", esto se logra asignando los valores con `<<-`, por ejemplo:

```
fn_suma <- function(d1,d2) {
  suma <<- d1+d2
  mul <<- suma*9
  cat(paste0("El resultado es:", mul))
  mul
}
```

Con  `<<-` tanto `suma` como `mul` no se crean en el entorno local, sino en el entorno padre o global en este caso, así ya deberías ver los valores en el panel del entorno global, pero esto no es una buena práctica, es preferible que las variables de una función sean realmente locales.

Con respecto a:

> ¿cómo puedo modificar la función para que sum se guarde de forma que
> pueda acceder a su resultado desde la ventanita de values?

Ya te han dado una respuesta adecuada, hay que retornar el valor, lo que puede hacerse, simplemente colocando como última instrucción de la función, el nombre de la variable, o bien haciendo un `return()` explicíto.